# Update input value onchange/oninput of another using calendar selector

Tags: javascript, onchange

I need to update the value of one field if the value of another changes. The field I want updated contains a timestamp, and field whose value may change contains a date (yyyy-MM-dd). The change is made **via a calendar selector**, which is probably the reason why the `onchange` and the `oninput` events fail to call the function.

Here's my code:

```
<input required class="short" type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="<?php echo (isset($startdate) ? $startdate : "") ?>" oninput="updateTimestamp();" />
    <input required class="short" type="text" id="startdate_u" name="startdate_u" value="<?php echo (isset($startdate_u) ? $startdate_u : "") ?>" />
    <a href="#" onclick="cal.select(document.forms['project'].startdate,'anchor','yyyy-MM-dd'); return false;" name="anchor" id="anchor"><img src="images/calendar_icon.png" /></a>
    <script>
        var cal = new CalendarPopup();
        function popup(mylink, windowname) {
            if (! window.focus)return true;
                var href;
            if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
                href=mylink;
            else
                href=mylink.href;
            window.open(href, windowname, 'width=500,height=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
            return false;
        }
        function updateTimestamp() {
            var startDate = document.getElementById("startdate");
            var newTimestamp = Math.round(new Date(startDate.value).getTime()/1000);
            document.getElementById("startdate_u").value = newTimestamp.toString();
        }
    </script>
```

Here's a link to the calendar code: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/source.html

I am not using JQuery.
Your advice is highly appreciated :)
The entire website is written according to HTML5 standards – I read that `oninput` should do the trick then but it doesn't. Tested on both Chrome and IE 11.

Comment: You aren't getting the `.value` for `startDate` and in your `Math.round(new Date(startdate)` the variable doesn't have an uppercase **D**. Try `Math.round(new Date(startDate.value).getTime()/1000);`

Comment: You're right. I just typed these which explains the typos. Earlier I tried both with `.value` and without. Not even a simple `alert()` is triggered.

Comment: Just tried with `Math.round(new Date(startDate.value).getTime()/1000);` too – nothing. I think the problem is that the `oninput` event doesn't fire because I change the date using the calendar selector, but no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calendar also defines a setReturnFunction which expects the name of the function to get the result.

So I think you need to set that to the name of the function that will receive the result, fill in your input and trigger any other functionality you may like.

Something like:

```
<script>
   function dateSelected(y,m,d){
   // Fill in your input as probably it will not be filled.
   // Trigger any additional functionality
    updateTimestamp();
    var dateField = document.getElementById("startdate");
    dateField.value = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
   }

   var cal = new CalendarPopup();
   cal.setReturnFunction('dateSelected');
   function popup(mylink, windowname) {
    if (! window.focus)return true;
     var href;
    if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
     href=mylink;
    else
     href=mylink.href;
    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=500,height=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    return false;
   }

   function updateTimestamp() {
    var startDate = document.getElementById("startdate");
    var newTimestamp = Math.round(new Date(startDate.value).getTime()/1000);
    document.getElementById("startdate_u").value = newTimestamp.toString();
   }
  </script>
```

**Note: quite a few things in the code can be improved, starting with the calendar.**